# How do I extract the body from an HTTP request in Clojure?

Tags: clojurescript

I am making an HTTP request:

```clj
(defn main-panel []

  (def API-URL "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random")

  (defn getFileTree []
    (go (let [response (<! (http/get API-URL
                                     {:with-credentials? false
                                      :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"}}))]
          (:status response)
          (js/console.log (:body response))))) ; prints a very complex data structure

  (go
    (let [result (<! (getFileTree))]
      (.log js/console (:body result)))) ; prints null

    :reagent-render
    (fn []
      [:h1 "kjdfkjndfkjn"]))
```

But I can't get to the "joke" in the returned object, array item 13:

[image]

How do I assign this value to a `let` or `def`?

Also, why does the second console.log print `null`?

### Update

I am now moving on from using `reagent` atoms to `reframe`.

This is my component that successfully `GET`s data, updates the re-frame 'database':

```clj
(defn main-panel []

  (def API-URL "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random")
  (def request-opts {:with-credentials? false})

  (defn getFileTree []
    (go (let [response (<! (http/get API-URL request-opts))]
          (re-frame/dispatch [:update-quote response]))))

  (defn render-quote []
    (println (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/quote])) ;successfully prints API data as in screenshot below
    (fn []
      (let [quote-data (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/quote])
            quote-text (if quote-data (:value quote-data) "...loading...")]
        [:div
         [:h3 "Chuck quote of the day"]
         [:em quote-text]])))

  (fn []
    (getFileTree)
    [render-quote]))
```

But this is the object I get back from the re-frame database:
[image]

As you can see it comes wrapped in the `Reaction` tags and I can't access the body or `value` any more. How do I access those?

Comment: I haven't used re-frame myself but from what I looked, `re-frame/subscribe` will get you a reaction, which is a wrapper around data (see here for details: https://reagent-project.github.io/docs/master/ManagingState.html#reactions ) for your use case, you should be able to get the nested map with `@quote-data`. I strongly recommend you to check this guide: https://purelyfunctional.tv/guide/re-frame-building-blocks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a small working version using the reagent template. Create a new project (assuming you have Leiningen installed) with: `lein new reagent chuck`. This will create a project with many dependencies, but it works out of the box.

Next, edit the file at `src/cljs/chuck/core.cljs` and edit it so it looks like the following:

```clj
(ns chuck.core
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]])
  (:require [reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]]
            [cljs-http.client :as http]
            [cljs.core.async :refer [<!]]))

(def api-url "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random")
(def request-opts {:with-credentials? false
                   :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"}})

(def api-response (atom nil))

(defn get-quote []
  (go
    (let [response (<! (http/get api-url request-opts))]
      (println response)
      (reset! api-response response))))

(defn render-quote []
  (fn []
    (let [quote-data (:body @api-response)
          quote-text (if quote-data (:value quote-data) "...loading...")]
      [:div
       [:h3 "Chuck quote of the day"]
       [:em quote-text]])))

(defn quote-page []
  (fn []
    (do
      (get-quote)
      [:div
       [:header
        [render-quote]]
       [:footer
        [:p "footer here"]]])))

;; -------------------------
;; Initialize app

(defn mount-root []
  (reagent/render [quote-page] (.getElementById js/document "app")))

(defn init! []
  (mount-root))
```

I'll explain the relevant bits:

- `init` will bootstrap the basics of the front-end, but in our case it's just calls `mount-root` which starts reagent telling it to call `quote-page` and placing the results in the DOM replacing the element with the ID of `app`.
- `quote-page` calls `get-quote` which will call the API using the cljs-http library. I'm not checking for errors here, but basically when the request completes (either success or error) it will read the results from the channel (using `<!`) and place the response in `response`. The key is that response is a *nested ClojureScript map* that you can inspect to check if the result was successful or not. Note that I'm also printing the results with `println` instead of JS interop (`.log js/console xxx`) because `console.log` will show the inner details of how the nested map is implemented, which is not relevant for this case.
- One the `response` is available, I store the results of the response in an `atom` called `api-response`. The key here is that the atom will contain nothing for a bit (while the request completes) and then the response will be inside it and reagent will take care of detecting the change and re-rendering.
- Finally, `quote-page` calls `render-quote` which generates the markup for rendering the quote or a placeholder while it loads.

[image: firefox console screenshot]

To run the whole thing, open a terminal and run `lein run` which will start a web server listening on port 3000 by default. In another terminal, run `lein figwheel` which will compile the ClojureScript code for you. One figwheel is ready it will start a REPL, and you can open the address http://0.0.0.0:3000/ in your computer to view the page.

Comment: Thanks @Denis for this AWESOME answer - I've got it working now.

For anyone else stumbling across this I found [this](https://medium.com/@roman01la/debugging-clojurescript-6e4d903e831) article that nicely explains the difference between `js/console.log` and `println` which was one of the major hurdles. 

One more question - to access nested properties of response objects you basically have to call `(:key value)` on the response which will then evaluate to the `value` itself? This would be the equivalent to `response.key` in JavaScript?

Comment: I have update the original post with one more question 